# Why sizeof works well on linux and encounter a runtime error on windows

Tags: c++, windows, sizeof, cout

I wrote a simple program in c++:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout<<sizeof(bool)<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

but when I compiled it with minGW and run it on windows7,a messagebox comeout saying Application stop working.but when I compiled it on linux with g++,it works well.How could this happen?
when I use printf on windows it works fine.Could anyone please explain why?

Comment: More information needed. "Encounter an error on windows" -> What error? At compile-time or runtime?  "It's dead..." -> What does this mean?

Comment: @RaymondChen Lol. Most elegant exploit ever.

Comment: If it compiling error, due to `bool` include `stdbool.h` will `typedef #define` that to bool and provide the constants true and false.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's dead?"  This looks like totally legal and legitimate C++ code.  Are you sure the program just isn't terminating immediately and therefore closing the window containing the output?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I added the missing information

Comment: @maple Not really. To you, does that provide any more information about the problem?

Comment: The problem is certainly **not** with `sizeof`; that is a compile-time operator. There is something else wrong. If `printf` works but `cout` does not, it seems like there is some C++ library issue due to it being compiled with minGW. Why, I'm not sure.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: `bool` is a built-in type in C++, a keyword; `stdbool.h` is not needed.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Do you mean that I should reinstall my minGW?

Comment: What happens if you change the statement to `cout << 1 << endl;`? Or `cout << "Hello, world" << endl;`? Or comment out that line altogether? I seriously doubt that `sizeof` or `bool` is the problem; as @JonathonReinhart: suggests, it's more likely a problem with your MinGW installation.

Comment: @KeithThompson  when I replaced the statement with cout << "Hello, world" << endl; it can print "Hello,world",and then a messagebox comeout saying Application stop working.is that mean I should reinstall?

Comment: @maple: Yes, you should probably reinstall.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you sure you have the latest C++ libraries? in the old one it is  just check this out.
and i think the new library is `std::cout<<""`  so i think you are using the old library. Try `<iostream.h>`

Comment: `<iostream.h>` is the old library; `<iostream>` is the new one.  The OP seems to be using the correct header.

Comment: Yes but he is using cout<< instead of std::cout<<

Comment: The OP is also using `using namespace std;` at the top of the program, which makes `std::cout` accessible as just `cout`.